# $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\forall\epsilon>0,\exists z\in\mathbb{Z},\ \exists n\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $|x-\frac{z}{4^{n}}|<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\forall\epsilon>0,\exists z\in\mathbb{Z},\ \exists n\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $|x-\frac{z}{4^{n}}|<\epsilon$

How can I prove this? I try to use Archimedean Property, but there is two dependent variables, anyone could help me with this?

Comment: As a tool, we need the fact that for any $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is an $n$ such that $\frac{1}{4^n}\lt \epsilon$.

Comment: Try to prove the statement with $z=1$.

Comment: Ok, I have done the proof of $\frac{1}{4^{n}} < \epsilon$, then how can I use this? @AndréNicolas

Comment: The idea is fundamentally simple. Take $x\gt 0$ for simplicity. Choose $n$ so that $\frac{1}{4^n}\lt \epsilon$. Consider $\frac{k}{4^n}$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$. There is a smallest $k$ such that $\frac{k}{4^n}\ge x$. This is our $z$.

Comment: Consider $z = \lfloor x4^n \rfloor$ when $n \gt - \log_4 \epsilon$

Comment: I got it, thanks for the help

Comment: 2OP: would you consider posting your solution as an answer?